# Code Inside Catch Block

Tags: refactoring, exception-handling, error-handling, conditions

This question is related to both of these questions - [Efficient try / catch block usage?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145941/efficient-try-catch-block-usage) and [Dealing with error in data - Idempotent approach](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271127/dealing-with-error-in-data-idempotent-approach).

When I encounter a void while reading a GIS data file I throw an Exception. This Exception is a subclass of java.lang.Exception. The question is of what happens after the void data exception is reached. Post processing would require that I go to another URL where the void filled data file is available and then download that and then proceed to read it in.

From the "efficient-try-catch-block-usage" question it appears doing inside this the catch block is a strict NO. Would it better then instead of throwing an application specific exception it is better to check for a return code or a post condition and proceed to do the post processing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much of a performance hit you can reasonably accept when throwing the exception.  If it only happens once, it might not be a big deal.  If it happens every line of the file, it could be a huge problem.

Normally exceptions are thrown when something happens that you can't do anything about, and execution is stopped.

Comment: when a single void is encountered I stop processing that file. I then go to the void filled URL and proceed to download that. You are saying this can be done inside the catch block ?

Comment: I'm not a fan of using catch blocks to control program flow, but yes, you could use it like a hacky `continue` statement.

Comment: Robert Harvey - not a big fan of hacky code :-)

Comment: Still, you could think of each file as a separate "process."  In that context, exceptions used in this way are perfectly legitimate.

Comment: you are saying it is fine to have detailed application logic inside catch blocks ?

Comment: You have a function.  It reads the lines of a text file and does something with each line.  If there's a problem with one of the lines, it throws an exception and stops.  Now wrap that function in a loop, so that it can handle more than one file.  See?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23993/discussion-between-gansub-and-robert-harvey).